# User permissions on a per-entry basis?

Tags: control-panel, permissions

I have a Structure section that contains most of the pages on my website.

We have users that need to edit only some of those pages. Since permissions are set on a per-section basis, right now they can edit either all or none of those pages.

How would I go about building custom user permissions for only some of those pages?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this?

Comment: I did not find a solution

Answer (score 3):

This might be considered more of a "workaround" than a technical solution, but I think it could actually solve your problem quite nicely...

**You can use [CP CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) and/or [CP JS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpjs) to show or hide certain fields.**

You'll probably find that the [CP Body Classes](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpbodyclasses) plugin is helpful for narrowing in on specific conditions. For example, you could show/hide certain fields based on a specific user group.

*Disclaimer: I wrote each of those plugins. Feel free to leave feedback on Github!*

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is not currently possible, Frabo.

As a potential, somewhat long-winded workaround... If it was a single user, you could make that person/User the Author of the entries which you want them to be able to edit, then uncheck the option (in Settings > Users > User Groups ) to "**Edit other authors’ entries**"

Be interesting to hear what others suggest...

Comment: Unfortunalety, multiple groups have to be able to edit the same page. Otherwise it's an interesting solution.